# How to Creating Azure and how to make it automation

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How to create Azure Secrets and  how to make it automation.

How to create Azure Secrets and  how to make it automation.

Answer (score 0):

There is detailed documentation for your topic: [Quickstart: Set and retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell)